# How do I pass an array as an argument?

Tags: bash, function

How do I pass an `array` to a function, especially if it is in the middle somewhere? Both `"${b}"` and `"${b[@]}"` seems to pass the first item only, so is there a way to both - call and retrieve it, correctly?

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

touch a b1 b2 b3 c

f()
{
    local a="${1}"
    local b="${2}"   
    local c="${3}"
    ls "${b[@]}" # expected b1 b2 b3
}

a=a
b=("b1" "b2" "b3")
c=c

f "${a}" "${b}" "${c}"
f "${a}" "${b[@]}" "${c}"

rm a b1 b2 b3 c
```

Comment: You can't really pass an array as an argument; arguments are just strings, not more complicated data structures. You can pass *the strings that are in an array* (each one as a separate argument), but you cannot pass the array itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash is a similar question from SO. It uses an idea based on Bash's *dynamic scoping* from pre-Bash 4.3 (where the accepted answer works).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `bash` shell, like in the `ksh` shell whose array design `bash` copied, `"${array[@]}"` expands to all the distinct element of the array (sorted by array index), and `"$array"` is the same as `"${array[0]}"`.

So to pass all the elements of an array to a function, it's `f "${array[@]}"`.

Now, a function's arguments are accessed via `"$@"`, so your functions  should be something like:

```
f() {
  ls -ld -- "$@"
}

f "$a" "${b[@]}" "$c"
```

Another option is to pass your array by name and use named references (another feature `bash` copied from `ksh` (ksh93)):

```
f() {
  typeset -n array="$1"
  ls -ld -- "${array[@]}"
}

f b
```

Or for `f` to take 3 arguments: a filename, an array name and another filename:

```
f() {
  typeset -n array="$2"
  ls -ld -- "$1" "${array[@]}" "$3"
}

f "$a" b "$c"
```

In virtually every other shell with arrays (`csh`, `tcsh`, `rc`, `es`, `zsh`, `yash`, `fish`), you just use `$array` to expand to all the elements of the array. In every other shell, arrays are also normal (non-sparse) arrays. A few caveats though: in csh/tcsh and yash, `$array` would still be subject to split+glob, and you'd need `$array:q` in `(t)csh` and `"${array[@]}"` in `yash` to work around it, while in `zsh`, `$array` would be subject to empty-removal (and again `"${array[@]}"` or `"$array[@]"` or `"${(@)array}"` works around it).

Comment: @Nishant Where exactly? Is it always the 2nd argument?

Comment: Yeah it is going to be the 2nd argument always. Does it change if it is the k-th argument?

Comment: @Nishant This should be clear from the last piece of code in this answer.

Comment: Note: `typeset -n` is not supported in `ksh88`, and neither is array assignment via `b=( b1 b2 b3 )`.

Comment: @jrw, Yes, `typeset -n` is from ksh93 while `array=(...)` is from zsh, but the awkward array design is from ksh83 (probably even earlier from the time David Korn wrote some extensions on the Bourne shell for some DB project in the early 80s).